# Bulk FindOrCreate in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Is it possible for me to use findOrCreate for multiple rows instead of just one? Whenever I tried finding multiple rows it only returned one

```
let a = model.findOrCreate({
        where: {
            ID: ["216","2809"]
        },
    })
```

in this case, a[0] is the row for "212" and a[1] is a boolean instead of the row for "2809"

Comment: maybe it would be useful to try ` bulkCreate` (look at its options)